# ReactJs and Singleton issue with updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, singleton

Firstable, I know its not good practice to share data like this in react App,
But - let say "I have no choice"
Now I have an issue with singleton in ReactJs.
I can see that if i trying to get instance of singleton - constructor works only once.
Inside constructor I have subscription to web socket which updates data inside singleton.
But then Im try to reach the data from different places in app - its not update - shows me version then I took instance. How can I solve it?

```
export default class Manager {
    constructor(){
        this.data = null;
        socket.on('event', this.parseData)
    }

    static getInstance(){
       if (!this.instance) {
         this.instance = new QuotasManager();
       }
      return this.instance;
    }
   
   parseData(data){ ///parsedata}
   
   getData(){ return this.data}

}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you use this class?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for disturb - I found that its my fault. I loose my scope then use callback on socket event. Just forgot to add arrow function to got my `this`